# Exlude rows not included in OR ? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I got this request :

```
SELECT *
FROM
  produits as P,
  fournisseur as F,
  caracteristiques as C, 
  liste_caracteristiques as Li 
WHERE P.fournisseur = F.reffournisseur 
  AND C.idCarac = Li.idCarac 
  AND P.refproduit = Li.refproduit 
  AND typeProd ='1' 
  AND prixpublicindicatif <= 450
  AND (libelleCarac = "Poids" AND valeur <= 1100
    OR libelleCarac = "Taille de l'écran" AND valeur IN('15cm', '8.3cm'));
```

The problem is: I got results with only C.libelleCarac = 'Poids' if poids <= 1100,
results with C.libelleCarac = 'Taille de l\'écran' if valeur = 15cm or 8.3cm,
results with C.libelleCarac = 'Taille de l\'écran' if valeur = 15cm or 8.3cm AND C.libelleCarac = 'Poids' if poids <= 1100

But I need only results with C.libelleCarac = 'Taille de l\'écran' AND C.libelleCarac = 'Poids' and exclude product with only one C.libelleCarac

Let me know if it's not clear

Comment: What exactly do you need in return? Do you really need to select all `select *`??

Comment: can you please explain lil more

Comment: @juergend the SELECT * is not important I just need a product name (P.nomproduit )

Comment: Then use `SELECT P.nomproduit` in the place of `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `nomproduit` column and take only those groups having both conditions

```
SELECT P.nomproduit
FROM produits as P
JOIN fournisseur as F ON P.fournisseur = F.reffournisseur 
JOIN liste_caracteristiques as Li ON P.refproduit = Li.refproduit 
JOIN caracteristiques as C ON C.idCarac = Li.idCarac 
WHERE typeProd ='1' 
AND prixpublicindicatif <= 450
AND 
(
    (C.libelleCarac = "Poids" AND C.valeur <= 1100)  OR
    (C.libelleCarac = "Taille de l'écran" AND C.valeur IN('15cm', '8.3cm'))
)
group by P.nomproduit
having count(distinct C.idCarac) = 2
```

Comment: It's working ! If I need to add another C.libelleCarac condition I just need to count(distinct C.idCarac) = 3 I suppose :)